# Syntax Error while Inserting variables into a table Visual Studios 2015 C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm confused at the moment about what it means exactly about my current syntax error issue while trying to save/insert answers into a table in my database. It worked fine when I attempted this with hardcoded variables but now is not the case.

Part of the error message:

> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Below is the code I'm using and the location where the error is pointing to. Thank you for any possible assistance and clarification.

```
protected void btnSaveAnswers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Int32 int32StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["StudentID"]);
        Int32 int32QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuestionID"]);
        String strAnswer = "";

        // Save the student's answer to the Answer table.
        // Develop the SQL call.
        String strSQL = "";
        strSQL = "INSERT ";
        strSQL += "INTO Answer ";
        strSQL += " (StudentID, QuestionID, Answer) ";
        strSQL += "VALUES ";
        strSQL += " ( " + int32StudentID + ", " + int32QuestionID + ", " + strAnswer + ")";
        // Define the network connection to the SQL Server database.
        SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OPT"].ConnectionString);
        // Create the SQL command object.
        SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        objSqlCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;
        objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        objSqlCommand.CommandText = strSQL;
        // Open the connection.
        objSqlConnection.Open();
        // Execute the Insert statement.
        objSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // Close the connection.
        objSqlConnection.Close();

        this.Master.MessageForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.Master.Message = "You have saved your answer for this question, click next to continue.";
    }
```

Comment: That's why you should use parameters instead of concatenation.

Comment: That has not been the correct way to build queries for a number of years now.  Five minutes of research would have gotten you any of several *thousands* SO posts explaining that and info on Parameters.

Comment: The professor for most of our CS courses at my college basically teaches us and then forces us to write it this way. Otherwise, we lose points for not following his examples.

Comment: Probably your professor need to take a look at some posts on Stack Overflow as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should not be building SQL statements like this, it is prone to many problems, but your issue is with your string, you do not have single quotes around it:

```
strSQL += " ( " + int32StudentID + ", " + int32QuestionID + ", '" + strAnswer + "')";
```

Need to add the single quotes around strAnswer like I have above

Use parameters outlined here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Your last single quote is in the wrong spot, it should be inside the double quote.

Answer (score 0):

The error is at this line

```
strSQL += " ( " + int32StudentID + ", " + int32QuestionID + ", " + strAnswer + ")";
```

As per your SQL Query and database the field `Answer` is a field of type `varchar` or `nvarchar`. This type of field always takes value of string type. Which is done by you already. But SQL Server database accept these values inside the single quotation `''`. Thus your solve is

```
strSQL += " ( " + int32StudentID + ", " + int32QuestionID + ", '" + strAnswer + "')";
```

as I've added a single quotation in front of `strAnswer` and at the last of `strAnswer`

Thank you.

Comment: You made the same mistake as Brad - the last single quote goes after the double quote immediately in front of the closing parenthesis.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for that. Thank you for your kind concern.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment about concatenation of strings. If you have to write a SQL query in code, you should user string interpolation.

If I had to do it, I would write it like this:

`String strSQL = $"INSERT INTO Answer  (StudentID, QuestionID, Answer) VALUES ( {int32StudentID}, {int32QuestionID}, '{strAnswer}')";`

That said, that is not why you have a syntax error. You are missing single quotes around your string variable. Try this:

`strSQL += " ( " + int32StudentID + ", " + int32QuestionID + ", '" + strAnswer + "')";`